# Accessing a stored list in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Is there a way to access a stored list in Racket without passing it new data? A list of past responses is stored using the following code in a program I'm working on.

```
(define (storage response lst)
  (cons response lst))
```

This makes a list by taking a response to a question and a previous list. I don't want to change what's in the list just simply see what's inside it. If other code is needed I will be happy to show what I have.

Comment: You are showing us the procedure that creates the list, but not the list itself, i.e. where it is stored. I guess somewhere you will find something like "(set! listname (storage newresponse listname))".

Comment: ya, if you want a global variable, you have to use set! somewhere or pass it along with every function call. (which can get awkward)

Comment: @WorBlux That's one of the things I don't like about Racket, you always have to pass the variable along. The good part is I have to think in new way to solve problems!

Comment: (define my-list (let ((local-list '())) (lambda things (if (null? things) local-list (begin (set! local-list (append things local-list)) local-list)))  Call this with no arguments to get the current list, call it with arguments to add them to the list and return the new list.

Comment: careful though, if assignment is not used sparingly you muck everything up with issues of state and time making it much harder to keep an accurate and abstract model of what the program is doing in your head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to access a list's elements in Racket is by using the `first` and `rest` procedures (or equivalently: `car` and `cdr`) to recursively iterate over a list. For example, let's say  that you want to find out if the list contains the `"404"` response:

```
(define responses '("302" "403" "404" "505"))

(define (find-response lst response)
         ; the list is empty, the element was not found
  (cond ((empty? lst)
         #f)
         ; `first` accesses the first element in the list
        ((equal? (first lst) response)
         #t)
        (else
         ; `rest` advances to the next elements in the list
         (find-response (rest lst) response))))

(find-response responses "404")
=> #t

(find-response responses "201")
=> #f
```

Of course, once you learn how this works, you can move and use existing procedures, for example [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._member%29%29) as suggested in the other answers. Please take a look at the list procedures [available for use](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html), you'll see that the most frequent operations are already implemented and at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

As currently constructed, you created a function called storage that takes response and a list and returns a new list with response as the head and lst as the tail.

If you want to get the head or tail of `(storage a l)` then you just call `(car (storage a l))` or `(cdr (storage a l))`- it's just a list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to access a stored list without passing it as new data.  See page 25, Section 6.3.2 in the [Scheme R5RS Specification](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/r5rs.pdf) for a full list of 'list accessing' functions.  Racket probably has more; other Scheme versions may have additional ones.

Here is an example.  To test if a 'response' has been seen already:

```
  (member response lst)
```

to count the number of responses:

```
  (length lst)
```